# How can I move children nodes with their parent node in SceneKit while using physics?

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit, physics, tvos

I have a rocket, earth and moon. My rocket is added as a child to the moon, the moon is added as a child to the moon orbital node, and the moon orbital node is added as a child to the earth. When the moon orbits around the earth, the rocket does not move with it while added as a physics body in the physics world. I would like the rocket's physics body to move relative to its parent moon node, not relative to the entire scene. That way it will orbit the earth along with the moon. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for physic bodies welding aka joints in `Scenekit's` jargon 
please take a look at this [DOCS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbehavior?language=objc).

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure which to use. I have a physics field applied to the moon and the rocket has force applied to it when tapped in order for it to be propelled. When the moon orbits it leaves the rocket behind, but Id like the rocket to move with it.

Comment: Perhaps I should use SCNPhysicsSliderJoint. Do you think this will fix the problem?

Comment: I don't really know which one do you need ;-) trying to imagine what you want to do - I think it is a ball -- I think with the described in comments addition of interactions you would probably add and remove the joints dynamically